# Difference between "&" in "int &a = b;" vs "int c = &d;"

Tags: c++

I'm just starting to learn about c++.

And I want to know about this

```
int g = &h;
```

what does "&h" mean in there?

I know that in here

```
int &e = f;
```

means "e" is referencing to "f".

So what are the difference between "&" in something like this

```
int &a = b;
int c = &d;
```

Answer (score -1):

& on the left-hand-side of = means reference.
On the right-hand-side, it means 'the memory address of'

e.g.

```cpp
int g = &h;
```

Is almost certainly an error.
It says, "create an integer, g, and set its value equal to the memory address of variable h.

Instead, you can have:

```cpp
int *g = &h;
```

It says, "create a pointer to an integer, g, and set its value equal to the memory address of variable h. g points to h.

And, as you said:

```cpp
int &e = f;
```

means e is now a reference to f